# performance of base64 icons in css vs external images for multiple uses

Tags: html, css, base64, background-image, data-uri

I am using about 30 images from the famfamfam silk icon set and have found [these in a base64 encoded format](http://mattclare.ca/blog/wp-content/silkcss.html)

The icons are stored in a .css file (approx 20kb) and each row of results will include 5 of the same icons - served up via https to modern browsers only.

I'm interested in knowing if I have 100 rows each including 5 identical icons referenced from a single external CSS file, will this perform better than individual image files or sprites?  The CSS file will obviously be cached but if the browser has to render the same background image over and over from a data-uri is this better or worse than a cached image file?

I've also noted this from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Advantages) but interested in others' opinions and experiences.

> Referencing the same resource (such as an embedded small image) more
> than once from the same document results in multiple copies of the
> embedded resource. In comparison, an external resource can be
> referenced arbitrarily many times, yet downloaded and decoded only
> once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to make a measurable test for that but I've created a following fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/chrisdanek/36Uk3/

It’s 1000 `div` elements with a background set to one of the famfamfam icons

```
div { 
  float: left; 
  background: url('data:image/png;base64,...') no-repeat; 
  width: 16px; 
  height: 16px; 
}
```

Now, if you take a peek in the Developer Tools in Chrome you’ll notice this icon is loaded only once, not 1000 times as a separate resource. I haven’t noticed a difference in memory load either when profiling this example and one using an url to the icon.

Other browsers may vary in this behaviour but my guess is as long as you don’t repeat yourself in the CSS and reuse the same encoded resource, you shouldn't see a difference based on the encoding itself. You will still get the benefit of one less HTTP request.